# Sessions and custom ajax in Drupal 6

Tags: ajax, drupal, session, drupal-6

I'm developing a custom module for Drupal 6. I have a problem with session variables and custom code with ajax functionality.

How can I access the session created by Drupal from the backend php script which is triggered by the ajax request?

e.g. in the module's .module file I add a custom php object to $_SESSION variable. I can access it within the .module file even if it's not the same page. When I execute a jQuery ajax request and try to access the object it's not available on the $_SESSION. It seems that the whole session has disappeared and the $_SESSION variable doesn't exist. Calling session_start() will create new session and blank $_SESSION array.

I've been stuck with this issue for two days. I just want to access the original session from the ajax request's backend script. Also, I cannot access global variables e.g. $base_url or $user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your Ajax calls going via the Drupal system? It sounds like you might be bypassing Drupal for them, which is just asking for this kind of trouble.

Comment: No, they're not handled via Drupal's ajax system since I couldn't get it working. All other ajax requests work just like usual but sessions fail. Is there no way to access session from custom ajax and its backend scripts? I do get the correct session name and id in the request but naming the session with that before session_start just creates a duplicate session with the same name and id. Though they have different domain (drupal has .domain.com and the new has just domain.com). Also the expireation with drupal session is a datetime and new is just "session".

Comment: Well, you're asking the wrong question - you should have asked why your ajax calls weren't working in Drupal. Rather than having the ajax calls routed outside of Drupal and asking how to integrate the two sessions.

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); // This makes all Drupal functionality available to my script
```

This worked for me (the script is in the root).

Answer (score 0):

Just summarizing the comments here.

Drupal has a great ajax framework. It handles a lot of the hard stuff for you, once you get it working.

If you go thought Drupal, all of the session handling will bedone for you.

If you ask another question about how to get it working, I'm sure we will help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll give it another shot and try to get Drupal's own ajax framework working. At first it was just so frustrating that I wanted to try a shortcut. I've found a couple of promising hands on tutorials. I'll post another (stupid) questions if I run to some issues I can't overcome.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, it is hard at first, and the docs are not great. D7's ajax framework is better, but even harder to use outside of the fapi.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and help. After trying several instructions, tutorials and blog posts I managed to get the Drupal's built-in ajax framework operational and all, including the sessions, are working great with the requests. I've learned that with Drupal things need to be done with Drupal and not "external" solutions as add-ins.

Coming from Joomla and Microsoft development Drupal's logic has mostly been pain in the *** :D

Answer (score 0):

In D7 I had to call `drupal_session_start()` directly before setting the `$_SESSION` variable.

```
drupal_session_start();
$_SESSION['type'] = "cat1";
```